# Problem with "rename" using regex (Linux)

Tags: debian, shell, regular-expression, rename

I have a backup script which is creating two files:

**a**) `db_mywebsite_2018-01-10_00-25.sql.gz` (150 MB)

**b**) `mywebsite1_2018-01-10_00-01.tar.gz` (2 GB)

I want to remove the date (XXXX-XX-XX_XX-XX) from file names. Because the backup is made daily, each file will have a different date in the name. For this, I'm using the following command:

```
rename -v -n 's/_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}//' *.sql.gz
```

For testing, I have `touch`ed two files `db_mywebsite_2018-01-10_00-25.sql.gz` and `mywebsite1_2018-01-10_00-01.tar.gz`

**Command**:

```
rename -v -n 's/_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}//' *.sql.gz
```

**Output**:

```
db_mywebsite_2018-01-10_00-25.sql.gz renamed as db_mywebsite.sql.gz
```

**1**. The problem is that despite the above message "db_mywebsite_2018-01-10_00-25.sql.gz renamed as db_mywebsite.sql.gz" when I check it via `ls -l` it looks like that file name hasn't been renamed.

**2**. Rename command (regex) is not working on file `mywebsite1_2018-01-10_00-01.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For the perl version of `rename`, the option `-n` means *no action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename.*  If you want the file to be renamed, don't use the `-n` option.  Thus, instead of:

   ```
   rename -v -n 's/_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}//' *.sql.gz
   ```

   Use:

   ```
   rename -v 's/_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}//' *.sql.gz
   ```
2. Consider:

   ```
   rename -v -n 's/_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}//' *.sql.gz
   ```

   The above command will only attempt to rename files ending in `.sql.gz`.  It will not to rename `mywebsite1_2018-01-10_00-01.tar.gz` because that file ends with `.tar.gz`.  To rename both files, try:

   ```
   rename -v -n 's/_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}//' *.tar.gz *.sql.gz
   ```

Comment: +1.  `-n` is for debugging/testing your regex without making potentially irreversible changes to your filenames.  i.e. it's a `--dry-run` option.